# Search problem, why does operator+ not give me any results?

Tags: support

In StackOverflow the search tips suggest using '+' to ensure terms appear in the search results. However if I enter the search:

```
+vs2008 +mfc +automation
```

It returns nothing at all, for some reason it doesn't seem to work if there is no space between the `+` and the search term, despite the fact that this is [what the search page's instructions say](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search)

On the other hand if I enter

```
+ vs2008 + mfc + automation
```

It returns results that do not include all the terms. Which makes it pretty well impossible to usefully search as I either get no results at all, or thousands of results that I don't have time to wade through.

How do you do a simple AND based search on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it seems, there are no questions with that combination of words on Stack Overflow.

All questions I was able to find either have `VS 2008` or any other full spelled variation of `visual studio 2008` in the text. [Searching for the tags only yielded one result, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008+mfc+automation).

As far as I can see, the search is working perfectly fine.

**Edit**: As [AakashM](/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151211/aakashm) pointed out...now your question appears...which renders this a caching issue...Dadadadaaaaaa...

Comment: It looks like you are right. I simply hadn't considered the possibility that there wouldn't be a single question matching the search terms. Classic PEBKAC.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect there's a caching issue involved, because **now** when you search for `+vs2008 +mfc +automation`, [your question is found](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2bvs2008%20%2bmfc%20%2bautomation).

Comment: I posted that question after I posted this one, so prior to posting that question the search returned nothing. Also this search "[tag]visual-studio-2008 +mfc +automation" still returns nothing.

Comment: @Neutrino The syntax would be [`[visual-studio-2008] +mfc +automation`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvisual-studio-2008%5D+%2Bmfc+%2Bautomation&submit=search)

Comment: Oh I see. It should be "[visual-studio-2008] +mfc +automation" <facepalm>